# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException while accessing a webservice

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, code-behind

I'm getting this unhandled exception error:

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' (Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation) occurred in the 3rd line of bool variable in the following code of BackEndUtil.cs

```
public static bool iMigrateProcess(string inputXML, out string outputXML,object objWebClient, string webSessionID)
{
  outputXML = "";
  object[] args = new Object[] { inputXML, outputXML };
  bool bSuccess = (bool)objWebClient.GetType().InvokeMember("Process", 
    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objWebClient, args);
  outputXML = (string)args[1];
  return bSuccess;
}
```

Here is the process method from other file (reference.cs)

```
[System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("http://BackendWebService.domain/Process", RequestNamespace="http://BackendWebService.domain/", ResponseNamespace="http://BackendWebService.domain/", Use=System.Web.Services.Description.SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle=System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
public string Process(string inputXML) {
  object[] results = this.Invoke("Process", new object[] { inputXML });
  return ((string)(results[0]));
}
```

Here I was consuming a web service (.asmx file) to stitch two image files. Here the inputXML seems to be fine containing XML of the file path of uploaded image file on server. However, the code doesn't go beyond line 3.
This code wasn't made by me so I have no idea how to troubleshoot this.

There are two InnerExceptions:
Make sure the file image is a valid managed assembly.
Make sure you have supplied a correct file path for the assembly.

[image: Call Stack Image]

Here is the code of iMigrateProcess from the Call Stack attached above.

```
 public static bool iMigrateProcess(cDataContainer inputDC, out cDataContainer outputDC, object objWebClient)
        {
            return iMigrateProcess(inputDC, out outputDC, objWebClient, "");
        }

        public static bool iMigrateProcess(cDataContainer inputDC, out cDataContainer outputDC, object objWebClient, string webSessionID)
        {
            outputDC = null;
            object[] args = new Object[] { inputDC, outputDC };
            bool bSuccess = (bool)objWebClient.GetType().InvokeMember("Process",
                BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, objWebClient, args);

            outputDC = (cDataContainer)args[1];

            return bSuccess;
        }
```

Comment: What is in the InnerException of TargetInvocationException?

Comment: There are two InnerExceptions:
Make sure the file image is a valid managed assembly.
Make sure you have supplied a correct file path for the assembly.

Comment: Whats the objWebClient class definition, what does "Process" method do ?

Comment: Those InnerExceptions are coming from .NET base class libraries or your code? What stack traces say?

Comment: @Novakov : You mean Call stack?

Comment: @The_Inquisitive: yes

Comment: @Novakov I attached the call stack and the methods used in it.